# Prevent status bar hide when presenting modal viewcontroller ios6

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, uistatusbar

I'm trying to present simple UIViewController modally by using segue.
after view controller is presented status bar is getting hidden, how to prevent status bar getting hidden ? 
i have one solution, just to put

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

on `viewDidApper` method, but its not a good solution, because anyway at first status bar is getting hidden

Comment: Are you calling the setStatusBarHidden somewhere else? I thought by default the status bar should not be hidden even though you present modal view controller.

Comment: I'm not setting status bar hidden anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. I hope this answer will help other people.
The problem is that i have ZBarReaderViewController inside my viewController , so inside ZBAr i believe there is some code to hide status bar. Since i didn't want to show ZBAr frame in full screen mode i set the `zbarController.wantsFullScreenLayout=NO;` and everything starts working fine.